# How to get the list of patches made by this git script?

Tags: android, c, linux, git, patch

from [this page](http://omappedia.org/wiki/PandaBoard_L27.12.1-P2_Release_Notes)

i found

```
cd ${YOUR_PATH}/L27.12.1-P2/kernel/android-2.6.35
git fetch http://review.omapzoom.org/p/kernel/omap refs/changes/22/13722/2 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

when i run this it makes paches and shows me how manny files are changed.

But what if i want to know by running this which files are changed and what lines are changed?

How can i get that info?

Comment: use git diff command, I'll suggest you to go through all the git commands.

Comment: You mean like `diffstat` style?

Comment: @TimPost yea diffstat style..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run `'git show'`, which will show all the changes from the current `HEAD` to the *previous commit* `on a line level`.